# what are some of the effects of breaking the sound barrier?

Tags: safety

I have tried googling it, and nothing came up, please help! I am trying to figure out what happens after a jet/aircraft breaks the sound barrier.

Comment: Generally, [loud noises](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/36357270/loud-noises.jpg)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [What happens when an aircraft breaks the sound barrier?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8846/what-happens-when-an-aircraft-breaks-the-sound-barrier)

Comment: What happens to what?  The airframe?  The pilot?  Observers on the ground?  Your question is pretty general, and there is all kinds of information about supersonic flight so I'm not sure what kind of key words you're searching on.

Comment: There is a loud boom that passes over the area.  It kind of makes buildings shake.  People I know who have been in planes while passing the speed of sound say the altimeter jumps.

Comment: If you have a mechanical clock inside with you, you can hear it tick.

Comment: @Mike Brass - "If you have a mechanical clock inside with you, you can hear it tick."  Only if it is in front of you.  If it is behind you the sound waves will not propagate forward to your ears.  Here is a link to a good demonstration of the effect:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TklvFQsBxRM